# How to save a Matrix with Super Table in it

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-supertable

I have an entry with a Matrix field, inside this field I have a Super Table as block type.  My fields data looks like below:

```
"title" => "test1"
"matrixHandle" => array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "type" => "sponsorshipRow"
    "fields" => array:2 [
      "sectionTitle" => "blablabla"
      "superTableHandle" => array:5 [
        0 => array:3 [
          "fields" => array:10 [
            "relatedArticle" => 325051
            ...
          ]
        ]
        1 => [...]
  1 => [...]
```

Then I loop these fields

```
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    $entry->setFieldValue($key, $value);
}
```

And last, I save the entry:

```
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($entry);
```

But every data is saved except for the super table block. The super table block is not even created. Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the super table array, there has to be a type there:

```
"superTableHandle" => array:5 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "type" => 1//the field's id
      "fields" => array:10 [
        "relatedArticle" => 325051
        ...
      ]
    ]
    1 => [...]
```

For me, this id is 1. It can be found in database by running this SQL

```
select * from supertableblocktypes;
```

But I ran the code below before and found out the field's id is 81 which is not working for me, I don't know why

```
dd(Craft::$app->fields->getFieldByHandle('matrixHandle')->blockTypeFields);
```